# Download web page content using Selenium Webdriver and HtmlUnit

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

For the following versions (JDK:8,JRE:8,HtmlUnit:2.17 and Selenium Webdriver:2.46), my this code works perfectly fine. When I say fine it means I am able to download the full web content (each and every line).

```
package  mypackage;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;      
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;     
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
public class HtmlUnitTest {             
public static void main(String[] args) {
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // Working fine
String baseUrl = "h t t p s : / / fourseasons . wd3 . myworkdayjobs . com / search / jobs";
driver.get(baseUrl);
WebDriverWait myWaitVar = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
try{
    myWaitVar.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("wd-FacetedSearchResult-ResultsPnl-facetSearchResult")));
}catch(Exception ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
String content=driver.getPageSource();
System.out.println(content);
driver.close();         
}
```

}

But when i change the driver to HtmlUnitDriver, it doesn't download the full content.

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
```

What i tried then:

```
1. WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
2. WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
3. WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_11);
```

Nothing works. 
What additional things I can add please suggest.

Comment: No @LaurentiuL. , its not duplicate. I am not getting full content, that's my issue. The above link (mentioned by you) have a problem of xpath. I think I have to set some more parameters or do something additional to get the content. I am new for selenium web driver so please suggest what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer guys. I enabled the javascript and it worked. So the new code is like:

```
public class HtmlUnitTest {             
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_38);
        driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);
        String baseUrl = "h t t p s : / / fourseasons . wd3 . myworkdayjobs . com / search / jobs";
        driver.get(baseUrl);
        WebDriverWait myWaitVar = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
        try{
            myWaitVar.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("wd-FacetedSearchResult-ResultsPnl-facetSearchResult")));
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        String content=driver.getPageSource();
        System.out.println(content);
        driver.close();         
    }      
}
```

Thanks all.