# why part of content disappear magically

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, html-parsing

I try to scraping the site https://www.pik.ru/search/vangarden/storehouse, and I got html from web-site succesfully and write it in the file, but when I try to get html ater it lots of information lost.

Examples:
what I've got from page (screen 1 that's not all)[image]

what I've got when I try to operate it (screen 2)[image]

Pls, help what's I do wrong
(Thank you!)
My code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import undetected_chromedriver
import time
import os

url = 'https://www.pik.ru/search/storehouse'

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/121.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/121.0.0.0'
}

proxies = {
    'https': 'http://146.247.105.71:4827'
}


def download_pages_objects(url):
    if os.path.isfile(r'C:\Users\kraz1\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Антон\python\парсинг\кладовочная\pik_links.txt') == True:
        os.remove(
            r'C:\Users\kraz1\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Антон\python\парсинг\кладовочная\pik_links.txt')

    list_links = []
    req = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxies)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, "lxml")

    for i in soup.find_all("a", class_="styles__ProjectCard-uyo9w7-0 friPgx"):
        list_links.append('https://www.pik.ru'+i.get('href')+'\n')

    with open(r'C:\Users\kraz1\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Антон\python\парсинг\кладовочная\pik_links.txt', 'a') as file:
        for link in list_links:
            file.write(link)


def get_list_objects_links(url):
    download_pages_objects(url)

    list_of_links = []
    with open(r'C:\Users\kraz1\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Антон\python\парсинг\кладовочная\pik_links.txt', 'r') as file:
        for item in file:
            list_of_links.append(item)

    return list_of_links


list_links = get_list_objects_links(url)

count = 0
for link in list_links:
    req = requests.get(link.replace('\n', ''),
                       headers=headers, proxies=proxies)

    with open('1.html', 'w') as file:
        file.write(req.text)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(req.text, 'lxml')
    print(req.text, '\n\n\n')
    print(soup.find_all('div', ''), '\n\n\n')

    with open('1.html', 'r') as file:
        scr = file.read()

    print(scr, '\n\n\n')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(scr, 'lxml')
    print(soup)

    count += 1
    if count == 1:
        break
```

I'd tried to operate it without write into the files, also change lxml, xml, html.parser -- it does not help (or I do something wrong)

Comment: BeautifulSoup does not execute javascript.

Comment: I think the actual cause is requests, not BeautifulSoup, but yeah it's the same general problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by JonSG, what you see in the browser is the result of the browser's engine executing JavaScript and modifying the page dynamically. Python's BeautifulSoup fetches the page's *contents* as-is.

What you're looking for is a web driver, for example, Selenium: [Download web page content using Selenium Webdriver and HtmlUnit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30749734)

Comment: I've got all what I needs - thanks a lot